# Characteristic Polynomial of transition matrix of $n$-cycle

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Let $P$ be the transition matrix of the deterministic random walk on the cycle $C_n$, i.e. $P \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ with

$$P_{i,j}=1\quad  \text{ iff }\quad  j=i+1 \mod n.$$

My guess is that the characteristic polynomial is given by

$$det(P-I x)=\begin{cases} x^n-1, & n \text{ even}\\1-x^n, & n  \text{ odd}\end{cases},$$

but I have no idea how to derive it and also no idea how to prove it. How would one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compute the determinant
$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
-x & 1 &   & \\
  & -x & \ddots & \\
  &    & \ddots & 1 \\
1 &    &        & -x
\end{vmatrix}
$$
I suggest you expand along the first column (I gave it some thought ; no induction needed here). Feel free to ask for details if you need more.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am a little bit confused with induction, since the matrices I get when I expand along the first column are not of the same type anymore. I tried to do it somehow iteratively and it gives the correct result but it is a little bit handwaving: I expand $n-2$ times along first column, giving $(-x)^{n-2} x^2$ for this first term coming from $-x$ in the first column and a $(-1)^{n-1}$ coming from $1$ in the first column, so taken together $(-x)^{n-2} x^2 + (-1)^{n-1} = (-x)^n + (-1)^{n-1}$, which seems to be correct. Is this what you thought?

Comment: @user136457 : If you expand along the first column, you get $2$ terms with $(n -1) \times (n-1)$ determinants of upper/lower triangular matrices, giving directly $(-x) (-x)^{n-1} + (-1)^n (1) = (-1)^n(x^n-1)$. That's why I said there is no induction needed after my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize that these are triangular matrices. If they were not, we would use that they stay the "same" (but smaller) from the second step on and we would use induction on these kinds of matrices, rather than on the first main type of matrix? So it might be confusing what I say, so I try to reformulate: if they were not triangular matrices, we would apply once an expansion to get 2 types of matrices, on both kinds of matrices we would apply induction and combine the results to get the final answer?

Comment: @user136457 : if they were not triangular, we would have had to think more. Because if they were not triangular it would be a completely different problem. But yes, sometimes it happens that the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ determinants we obtain using Laplace expansion have the same shape as the initial matrix (for instance, this happens in the case of triangular matrices!).

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful!